# How do I make a Html textbox to only take integer in Razor MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Haven't been able to find a good answer to my situation yet. I want this textbox to only take numbers and still have the id "SearchString2" so I can use it in my controller. Any idea how?

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
{
    @:<p><b>Customer ID:</b> @Html.TextBox("SearchString2")</p>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resolved here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902416/how-do-i-make-my-text-box-only-take-numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBox('SearchString2', new { @type = "number" })
```

This should set the type to be a number, you could then use attributes on your model to help limit it to only ints like so:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
[Required]
public string SearchString2 { get; set; }
```

You'll need to replace the regex with an actual regex and put an validation message in.

Here's more info on validation: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: Thanks, was what I was looking for :)

Comment: Actually now that I try it...doesn't work at all with the first one. And I only use searchstring2 when an admin is logged in which would make it a bad idea to put it in the model.

Comment: What I do get is a textbox which is automatically filled out with "type = "number"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think the correction needed to the above answer is

```
@Html.TextBox('SearchString2',null, new {@type="number"})
```

otherwise type=number shows up in the value.