# How do I make my text box only take numbers?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to set it so that you can only input values in the textbox, plain and simple. But the picture shows the result I get. Any idea what the problem is? I had one text box set up like this a few months back so I know that something in the lines if this should work.

[image: Picture of the result of the code]

Html code:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
{
    @:<p><b>Customer ID:</b> @Html.TextBox("SearchString2", new {@type="number"})</p>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@Html.TextBox("SearchString2", null, new { @type="number" })` - your using the wrong overload

Comment: You should post this as an answer and I will mark it :) @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using the wrong overload of `Html.TextBox()` ([this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29)) where the second parameter is the value to display. You need to use [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString2", null, new { @type="number" })
```